# Dynamic provisioning not working in aws eks for ebs volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to run hlf operator to create a hyperledger network for my project. The issue is that all the pods get stuck due pvc issue. The pvc always remains in pending state. I tried installing csi driver for aws ebs but it doesn't help. These are my yaml files.

CSI Driver :

[CSI Driver Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q5cd.png)

Storage Class :

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  type: gp2
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

PVC :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-csi-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web-server
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: my-volume
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ebs-claim
```

Result :

[PVC is stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJcRr.png)

The pv doesn't get created .

I would really appreciate some help on this. I've been struggling with this issue for a week now.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Check the logs of ebs csi pods, if there are any errors while doing dynamic provisioning. Hope all the service account IAM role and permission are correct as per documentation. Check on these aspects